# What's the difference between python version x.y and x.y.z, like 2.6 and 2.6.9?

Tags: python, version

We can find both 2-section version and 3-section version on python.org/ftp, can I assume that 2.5 EQUALS 2.5.0 and 2.6 EQUALS 2.6.0 ? Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

The versioning scheme is defined:  `major.minor.micro` (see [`sys.version_info`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.version_info)).

Generally speaking, you'll see big changes between major versions (which may be backwards incompatible).  Smaller features will be added between minor versions, but things should be mostly backward compatible and micro versions are mostly just bug-fixes.

Comment: So, I guess 2.5 means 2.5.0 for version 2.5 initial release, and 2.6 means 2.6.0, and so on. And I checked the file info in the python.org/ftp, the date of "last modified" shows the time line.
Thanks for reply!